# Проблема с SCSS + Sourcemaps(?)

Tags: gulp, scss, sass, sourcemap

Собираю простенькую gulp-сборку под свои нужды. Среди прочих пакетов есть gulp-sourcemaps, т.к. имею небольшую иерархию по scss-файлам (в частности, помимо основного "style.scss" есть еще "mixins.scss", куда пишу миксины, лежит все в одной папке).

Суть проблемы: первой строкой в "style.scss"  делаю  @import "mixins", несколькими строками ниже использую его посредством @include... и все работает, но при использовании, к примеру @include по отношению к тэгу h1 devtools указывает, что стили для h1 берутся из файла "mixins.scss", хотя @include прописан в "style.scss".

Подскажите пожалуйста - как сделать так, чтобы стили тэгов мапились из "style.scss"?
Мб неправильно настроен sourcemaps или следует использовать другой плагин?